# How to show the image for select list view row item in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell  How to show the image for select list view row  item in sencha touch?.If user select the row need to show tick symbol in right hand side and it will go to another view.after user press select text view.I need to maintain the image in same position

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, here when you will select any row, icon will be shown on right side.

Define itemTpl of list like

```
itemTpl: '<div>{Name}<img id = "checklist-{id}" style = "height:20px;width:20px;float:right"src =resources/icons/icon.png  hidden></img></div>',
```

//make sure id field is unique field here to define Id for icons

And In itemTap event of list do this

```
onListItemTap: function (item, index, target, record) {

    // get all icons by tag img, you can use class also if you define
    var allcheckeditems = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 

    // first hide all icons 
    for (var i = 0; i < allcheckeditems.length; i++) {
        allcheckeditems[i].hidden = true;
    }

    // show only selected row icon
    var selected = document.getElementById('checklist-' + record.data.id);
    selected.hidden = false;
}
```

Feel free to ask me if you have any confusion.